# Is it possible to create a NN of SIN prediction with 100% accuracy? Which one is the best?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, trigonometry, prediction

According to the

https://github.com/flo7up/relataly-public-python-tutorials/blob/master/009%20Time%20Series%20Forecasting%20-%20Measuring%20Model%20Performance.ipynb

I've changed the number of epochs to 10.000 and got an accuracy of 0.3%
How is it possible to get the accuracy to 0?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely try a deeper net to make sure it can adequately represent the data, but the problem with regression algorithms is that as you get closer to the goal, the loss function evaluates smaller and smaller and you basically never reach 0.

Also I see you imported dropout from keras layers, that will help for validation purposes but it will make your training process harder, essentially making it impossible to reach 0 training error if you did use it in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is literally no way to make the test accuracy to 100%. Increasing the number of epochs only lead to maximizing the training loss, instead finally decreasing the test accuracy due to overfitting.

Even one of the fundamental tasks of machine learning, MNIST doesn't have a 100% classifier https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-classification-on-mnist.